# Scrolling in viewport bootstrap tour

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tour

I have an issue with bootstrap tour.

I have a very long page, and the tour needs to work on mobile devices as well. Unfortunately the bootstrap tour function `scrollIntoView()` doesn't seam to work at all, as if i'm at the top of the page, it doesn't scroll down till the element i want to highlight.

Here's _scrollIntoView bootstrap tour code:

```
Tour.prototype._scrollIntoView = function(element, callback) {
      var $element, $window, counter, offsetTop, scrollTop, windowHeight;
      $element = $(element);
      if (!$element.length) {
        return callback();
      }
      $window = $(window);
      offsetTop = $element.offset().top;
      windowHeight = $window.height();
      scrollTop = Math.max(0, offsetTop - (windowHeight / 2));
      this._debug("Scroll into view. ScrollTop: " + scrollTop + ". Element offset: " + offsetTop + ". Window height: " + windowHeight + ".");
      counter = 0;
      return $('body, html').stop(true, true).animate({
        scrollTop: Math.ceil(scrollTop)
      }, (function(_this) {
        return function() {
          if (++counter === 2) {
            callback();
            return _this._debug("Scroll into view.\nAnimation end element offset: " + ($element.offset().top) + ".\nWindow height: " + ($window.height()) + ".");
          }
        };
      })(this));
    };
```

I've been searching everywhere for this issue, and already tried some of the suggestion founded on the bootstrap tour support page, but nothing.

The default scrollTop value is the following:

```
scrollTop = Math.max(0, offsetTop - (windowHeight / 2));
```

and basically it calculates the element offset and it scrolls it to the middle of the window.
Now, i think that the problem i have is that if the offset is very long (let's say 1100px on a small mobile device with window.height() 480px) the result of the above will be `1100 - (480/2) = 860px`, still below the viewport.

Do you have any suggestions at all on what formula should I use to scroll the element to inside the viewport reliable in any case and on any device?

Here's what i tried so far:

```
var offsetTop = $element.offset().top;
$('body, html').animate({
 scrollTop: scrolltop},300);
```

and i tried these different `scrolltop` formulas:

```
var scrollTop = (windowHeight / 2) + (offsetTop - windowHeight) + $element.height()
var scrolltop = (windowHeight / 2) + (offsetTop - windowHeight)
var scrollTop = (windowHeight / 2) + (offsetTop - windowHeight) - $element.height()
var scrollTop = $element.height()
```

But no luck till now.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Comment: could you post a fiddle?

Comment: For some reason, it seams to work in the fiddle...
i guess it's something to do with my website. Here's the fiddle anyway -> http://jsfiddle.net/r771w75s/